# Google Maps API return zero result while Google Maps UI gives the right return

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Not sure how to proceed on this, but I got different results between the Google Maps API vs Google Maps UI.

```
$ curl -s -X GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Saint+George+AU&key=API_KEY'

# Got zero result (I should expect at least one result in here)
```

```
curl -s -X GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Saint+Georges+AU&key=API_KEY' | jq .results[].formatted_address
"St Georges SA 5064, Australia"
"St George QLD 4487, Australia"

# Got two result
```

I wonder if this is a bug in the Google Maps API.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug to the Google Maps API. `Saint George AU` returns `ZERO_RESULTS`, while `Saint Georges AU` has `St George QLD 4487, Australia` in the response. You can report this at the Public Issue Tracker https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Comment: Have you tried the places API?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating [a bug ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235119900) in the Geocoding API issue tracker. While they admitted the issue was on their side, they closed my request as *Won't Fix (Infeasible)*!

Comment: That "answer" you received is just unacceptable. I don't know if you got that answer from the new intern or what happened there but it's unacceptable.

Comment: If this is important for you, you can try to report the same issue on the [Places API issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:18887). Maybe there are better chances that you get it fixed if you report it there (as it's not really a geocoding issue but more a *missing* place issue).

Comment: you know it is Google, the answer posted here is more for the knowledge sharing (as I did not know the process when I firstly created the issue):(

Comment: No problem with *your* answer. The issue is the answer you received in the issue tracker. I have read it 3 times and it really doesn't make ANY sense. I would post the same request in the Places API tracker if this was important to me.

Comment: Aha, I see your point, what is your issue report, I can maybe copy yours. Thanks!